# error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, c++17

So I'm writing a code that gives me the "opposite" letter on the ASCII table in c++. I'm running into the error

```
main.cpp:28:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
string letter_swap(ref_word){
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::noskipws;


string word;
string &ref_word = word;

string letter_swap(ref_word){

  int diff;
  cin >> ref_word;
  num_word = static_cast<int>(ref_word);

  if (65 <= num_word  & num_word <= 90){
    diff = 90 - num_word + 65;
    return diff;

} else if (97 <= num_word  & num_word <= 127){
    diff = 90 - num_word + 65;
    return diff;

} else{
    return ref_word;
  }

 }
```

I really can't tell where I'm missing the ;
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You haven't specified arugument type in the `letter_swap()` function, instead you have simply passed a reference to a string. The compiler interprets it as new string variable definition of `letter_swap` and hence complain about the missing `;` or `,`.

Comment: You should learn the differences between `&` and `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the argument type for ref_word.

```cpp
string letter_swap(string& ref_word){
```

These look like they shouldn't be there:

```cpp
string word;
string &ref_word = word;
```

You might also want to use && instead of &.

```cpp
 if (65 <= num_word && num_word <= 90)
```

You have not declared num_word as a variable, and you can't convert a numerical text value into a numeric value like this:

```cpp
  num_word = static_cast<int>(ref_word);
```

You probably want to be doing something along these lines:

```cpp
  size_t sz;
  int num_word = std::stoi(ref_word, &sz);
```